# Inherits from one basetable? Good idea?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to create a base table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS basetable
(
    id              BIGSERIAL       NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    createdon       TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL DEFAULT(NOW()),
    updatedon       TIMESTAMP       NULL
);
```

Then all other tables will inherits this table. So this table contains the ids of all records. Does it becomes performance problems with more then 20 billion records (distributed on the ~10 tables).

Comment: Does *what* become a performance problem?  Managing tables with 20 billion rows suggests performance challenges.  These can be addressed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is it a good ideo to handle records in this strukture?

Comment: Will you ever query this `basetable`? If not, there are no performance penalty on this approach. -- However a single serial will run out of available values faster than multiple, independent serials.

Comment: No, I won't. Thanks @pozs for your comment.

Comment: Also, you might want to read the [*caveats*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS) section on inheritance. It *may not* apply to you, but it's generally good to know, if you want to use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Having one table from which "all other tables will inherit" sounds like a strange idea but you might have a use case that is unclear to us.

Regarding your question specifically, having 20B rows is going to work but as @Gordon mentioned it, you will have performance challenges. If you query a row by ID it will be perfectly fine but if you search rows by timestamp ranges, even with indexes, it will be slower (how slow will depend on how fast your server is).

For large tables, a good solution is to use table partitioning (see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Table_partitioning). Based on what you query the most in your `WHERE` clause (`id`, `createdon` or `updatedon`) you can create partitions for that column and PostgreSQL will be able to read only the partition it needs instead of the entire table.

Comment: sorry, but it does not answer my question. I checked both versions (inheritance from basetable and don't use inheritance) and inheritance from basetable goes evil. A simple count of all records of 2million records takes 10 seconds for execution. I avoid the basetable.